# angularjs json schema form UI

Tags: angularjs, forms, jsonschema

I would like to create form out of below in angular js where it can only allow either a,b or c,d? Can someone please help on this. anyOf etc is not working. Angular is creating form for rest out of json schema but not for below

```
    "test": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "a": { "type": "string" },
        "b":   { "type": "string" },
        "c": { "type": "string" },
        "d": { "type": "string" }
      },
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": [ "a", "b" ] },
    { "required": [ "c", "d" ] }
  ]
}
```

Json Schema above has test as field and 4 properties and two are needed

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the ['How to Ask a good question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937).

Comment: I'm fairly certain angular-schema-form doesn't support the boolean logic keywords (`oneOf`, etc). I'm pretty sure you are going to need to do this validation another way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using angular-schema-form, boolean logic keywords (like oneOf) are not yet supported.

> Sometimes the validation you want is tricky to express in a JSON
>   Schema or Schema Form does not support it (yet), like anyOf and oneOf.

https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#custom-validation